# How can I eager fetch content of custom types in a ContentManager query?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I'm running into some n+1 performance issues when iterating over a collection of ContentItems of a custom Type that I created solely through migrations.

```cs
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("MyType", part => part
    .WithField("MyField", field => field
        ...
    )
);

ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("MyType", type => type
    .WithPart("MyType")
);
```

Every time I access a field of this part a new query is performed. I can use QueryHints to avoid this for the predefined parts

```cs
var myItems = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query().ForType("MyType")
            .WithQueryHints(new QueryHints().ExpandParts<LocalizationPart()
            ...
);
```

but can I do this for the ContentPart of my custom type too? This does not seem to work:

```cs
var myItems = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query().ForType("MyType")
            .WithQueryHints(new QueryHints().ExpandParts<ContentPart>()
            ...
);
```

How can I tell Orchard to just get everything in one go? I'd prefer to be able to do this without writing my own HQL or directly addressing the repositories.

**Example:**

```cs
var myItems = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query().ForType("MyType");

@foreach(var item in myItems.Take(100)) {
    foreach(var term in item.Content.MyItem.MyTaxonomyField.Terms) {
        // Executes 100 queries
        <div>@term.Name</div>
    }
}
```

TaxonomyField doesn't store ids and using the TaxonomyService inside of the loop wouldn't improve performance. Right now, to work around this, I fetch all `TermContentItems.Where(x => myItems.Select(i => i.Id).Contains(TermPartRecord.Id))` from the repository outside of the loop as well as a list of *all* the terms of the Taxonomy that the field is using. Then inside the loop:

```cs
var allTermsInThisField = termContentItems.Where(tci => tci.TermsPartRecord.Id == c.Id)
.Select(tci => terms.Where(t => t.Id == tci.TermRecord.Id).Single()).ToList()
```

I'm not a very experienced programmer but this was the only way I could see how to do this without digging into HQL and it seems overly complicated for my purposes. Can Orchard do this in less steps?

Comment: That's a little weird, as fields are persisted onto content item records, which should be brought down from the db on the first query. Can you share an example of the main query, and of the additional query that's being emitted when you ask for a field's value? You can obtain them from MiniProfiler, for example.
FWIW, I've written about querying fields using HQL here: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/querying-orchard-fields-with-hql but that should only be necessary when *filtering* on fields, not when querying for their values.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I added an example to my post. I didn't bother with the profiler yet because I realise now that the TaxonomyField is probably the odd one out here.

Comment: Aaaah, yes, some crucial information was missing, i.e. that the field in question is a taxonomy field, which uses additional tables rather than the storage space on the content item record. So yes, the most elegant solution would probably to use HQL, but what you've done seems to work. You can also take a look at `TermsPartHandler`, which does some interesting stuff with `new QueryHints().ExpandRecords("ContentTypeRecord", "CommonPartRecord", "TermsPartRecord");`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.