# Accessing info from CommonPart is extremely slow?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'm new to Orchard and this must be something involving how the underlying data is stored.

The joining with `CommonPart` seems fast enough, like this:

```
var items = _contentManager.Query<MyUserPart, MyUserPartRecord>("someTypeName")
                           .ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published)
                           .Join<CommonPartRecord>().List().ToList();
```

That runs fairly fast. But whenever I try accessing some field in `CommonPart`, it runs extremely slow like this:

```
var items = _contentManager.Query<MyUserPart, MyUserPartRecord>("someTypeName")
                           .ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published)
                           .Join<CommonPartRecord>().List()
                           //access some field from commonpart
                           .Select(e => new {                               
                               User = e.As<CommonPart>().Owner.UserName
                            }).ToList();
```

The total data is just about `1200` items, and the time it needs is about `5 seconds`, it cannot be slow like that. For a simple SQL query run in background, it should take a time of about 0.5 second or even less than.

I've tried investigating the Orchard's source code but found nothing that could be the issue. Everything seems to go into a blackbox at the accessing point of `IContent`. I hope someone here could give me some suggestion to diagnose and solve this hard issue. Thanks!

**Update**:

I've tried debugging a bit and seen that the following method is hit inside the `DefaultContentManager`:

```
ContentItem New(string contentType) { ... }
```

Well that's really interesting, the query is just asking for data without modifying, inserting and updating anything. But that method being hit shows that something's wrong here.

*Update*:

With @Bertrand Le Roy's comment, I've tried the following codes with `QueryHint` but looks like it does not change anything:

```
var items = _contentManager.Query<MyUserPart, MyUserPartRecord>("someTypeName")
                           .ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published)
                           .Join<CommonPartRecord>()
                           .WithQueryHints(new QueryHints().ExpandParts<CommonPart>())
                           .List()
                           //access some field from commonpart
                           .Select(e => new {                               
                               User = e.As<CommonPart>().Owner.UserName
                            }).ToList();
```

and this (without `.Join`)

```
var items = _contentManager.Query<MyUserPart, MyUserPartRecord>("someTypeName")
                           .ForVersion(VersionOptions.Published)
                           .WithQueryHints(new QueryHints().ExpandParts<CommonPart>())
                           .List()
                           //access some field from commonpart
                           .Select(e => new {                               
                               User = e.As<CommonPart>().Owner.UserName
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: You seem to be facing a select n+1 issue, where you fetch a fair number of content items, and then try to lookup the Owner of each, which will trigger a new request for each item. So that's 1201 SQL queries for something that should be done in 1. That is typically fixed by being more explicit and eager about what you're going to need, using `QueryHint`, or switching to using HQL altogether. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203555/how-can-i-eager-fetch-content-of-custom-types-in-a-contentmanager-query for a similar case.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy thanks for your link, I've tried using `QueryHint` but looks like it doesn't change anything, please see my last update above, maybe I've used `QueryHint` in a wrong way?

Comment: Thanks for including the new queries. I think the issue may be in the `Select`. Accessing the `Owner` property causes the lazy loader in `CommonPartHandler` to ask the content manager to load the user content item: `_contentManager.Get<IUser>(part.Record.OwnerId)`. I'm not sure how to get the `Owner` content item to by included in the query, but HQL may be a better choice in this case, for its flexibility. Another approach could be to first get the set of distinct owner ids as the result of a first query, then query the content manager for those ids (which is easily done in a single operation)

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I've tried using `Repository` directly to join the `CommonPartRecord` and it's just fast as expected. Anyway it would be much more convenient with the code I posted in my question but it's slow and I cannot use it. There must be something wrong here because I think Orchard should support that very common case so that we don't have to use `Repository` directly. I think your suggestion about `HQL` is something in lower level compared to using `Repository`, really I always try to avoid low level code if possible.

Comment: Actually, `Repository` is only there for internal usage by Orchard, and should pretty much never be used by module developers. It is actually lower-level than HQL, because it acts at the table level, whereas HQL operates at the level of the ORM, and understands about higher-level mapped entities.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy well I think Repository is at a higher level because it uses NHibernate in some way similar to Entity Framework, and I understand that HQL is at the same level with Entity SQL, using ORM we can just deal with LINQ and not with SQL or anything like that directly, which should be done at a lower level.

Comment: I'm one of the people who designed all that in Orchard, so think what you will, and feel free to disregard my advice, but what's going on is pretty clear to me (as I've explained in my 2nd comment), and there's at least two simple ways to work around the issue. 1st, you can use HQL and craft a query that gives you everything you need up front in 1 operation. 2nd, if you don't want to use HQL for whatever reason, you can make a 1st content manager query to get the set of owner ids, and then make a second query for those Ids and get everything you need with a total of 2 queries instead of 1201.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the `Owner` property from your `Select` causes the lazy loader in `CommonPartHandler` to ask the content manager to load the user content item: `_contentManager.Get<IUser>(part.Record.OwnerId)`. This happens once per content item result from your query, so results in a select n+1 where `n = 1200` according to your question.

There are at least two ways of avoiding that:

1. You can use HQL and craft a query that gives you everything you need up front in 1 operation.
2. You can make a 1st content manager query to get the set of owner ids, and then
   make a second content manager query for those Ids and get everything you need with a total of 2 queries instead of 1201.