# ILocalizedStringManager is reused unexpectedly across requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, orchardcms

I think this is really unexpected, because the `ILocalizedStringManager` is `IDependency` and that means it should always be created for each request.

I put some logging in the implementation class like this:

```
public class LocalizedStringManager : ILocalizedStringManager
{
    private readonly ITranslator _translator;
    public LocalizedStringManager(ITranslator translator)
    {
        _translator = translator;
        //we defined an OID on ITranslator to help debug this
        Debug.Print($">>>>>>>>> Init LocalizedStringManager ... ({_translator.OID})");
    }
    public string GetLocalizedString(string scope, string text, string cultureName)
    {
        return _translator.Translate(text).Text;
    }
}

public interface ITranslator : IDependency, IDisposable {
    string Translate(string text);
    Guid OID {get;}
}

public class Translator : ITranslator {
   public Guid OID {get;}
   public Translator(){
       OID = Guid.NewGuid();
   }
   public string Translate(string text){
       //...
   }
   public void Dispose(){
       Debug.Print($">>>>>>>>> Disposing ... {OID}");
   }
}
```

For the first request, I can see it printed out

```
>>>>>>>>> Init LocalizedStringManager ... 086a1487-bad9-481d-92f0-4615b9c6c5fd
```

then finally the referenced `ITranslator` is disposed, and prints the following:

```
>>>>>>>>> Disposing ... 086a1487-bad9-481d-92f0-4615b9c6c5fd
```

So everything is fine here, but somehow the next request (from browser) triggers the `LocalizedStringManager` via a `NullLocalizer`, and it's strange that I did not see any line like `>>>>>>>>> Init LocalizedStringManager ...` printed, but right before where it threw exception, I have a logging line printing out the `ITranslator` OID and it matched the value `086a1487-bad9-481d-92f0-4615b9c6c5fd`, really confusing.

Here is the code run for the second consecutive request:

```
public interface ISomeService : IDependency {
     SomeModel LoadData();
}
public class SomeService : ISomeService {
    public Localizer T {get;set;}      
    public SomeService(){
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }  
    public SomeModel LoadData(){
        //use the Localizer T here, such as to translate some text
        var model = new SomeModel();
        model.SomeText = T("SOME_KEY");
        //...
        return model;
    }
}
```

So the `T(...)` will trigger some `LocalizedStringManager`, and really I would expect it to create a new one (with new `ITranslator` referenced inside), but somehow it ***reused*** the one created in the request before (because I did not see any line like `>>>>>>>>> Init LocalizedStringManager ...` printed this time.
Also finally it will call the reused `ITranslator` (its `Translate` method) BUT this has been disposed before (after the request before), and now it threw an exception saying something like this:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in Autofac.dll
>
> An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
> Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed.

Everything seems to be out of my control. All are setup by the `Orchard` framework. I don't really understand how that `LocalizedStringManager` can be reused so easily? It should never be reused that way. We've encountered this kind of exception fairly frequently now (after trying to globalize our websites with multi-language support).

It's especially that this is not always reproducible (I mean it happens intermittently). I hope someone experienced with `Orchard` enough to at least give me some good suggestions for which could cause this issue.

### Update

I cannot provide the exact actual code (word by word), but the main logic can be like following (the most different things here are `IDisposable` not being implemented and `IRepository` being used in `ITranslator` implementation):

```
public interface ITranslator : IDependency {
    string Translate(string text);
    LanguageInfo GetCurrentUserLanguage();
}

public class LanguageInfo {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string DisplayName {get;set;}
}

public class Translator : ITranslator {       
   readonly IRepository<LanguageRecord> _languageRepo;
   readonly IOrchardServices _orchardServices;
   public Translator(IRepository<LanguageRecord> languageRepo, 
                     IOrchardServices orchardServices){
      _languageRepo = languageRepo;
      _orchardServices = orchardServices;
   }
   public LanguageInfo GetCurrentUserLanguage() {
       if(_orchardServices.WorkContext.CurrentUser == null){
          //obtain the language for not-logged-in user from his browser's cookie
          var langCode = _orchardServices.WorkContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["LangCode"] ?? "en";
          //get full language info
          //this is where the exception thrown (because of using the disposed repository)
          var fullInfo = _languageRepo.Table.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Code == langCode);
          return new LanguageInfo { Name = fullInfo.Name, DisplayName = fullInfo.DisplayName };

       } else {
          //obtain from DB the settings for the current user
          //however my test is for the case user not logging in 
          //So this branch is not important in this specific question.
          //...
       }
   }
   public string Translate(string text){
       //get current user language
       var lang = GetCurrentUserLanguage();
       //do the translation … (not important in this specific question)
       //...
   }   
}
```

Again I must say that this happens ***intermittently***, no way to ensure that it can be reproducible easily (that's the hardest thing to figure out why) especially after you can reproduce it once. As in my case, right after starting the homepage, the `GetCurrentUserLanguage` is called some times (for each translation), everything is fine. But all the calls are originated from `T(…)` ***inside razor views***.

However after that clicking one link (calling to the api `ISomeService`) will throw the exception, some others do use translation but they use `T` as part of Orchard's WebPage base (rendered in razor view), those don't cause the exception at least the first time I try navigating through the website. It's strange now that (as I've described by using the word ***intermittently***) by re-visiting that link, the exception does not throw. Actually from this time on I can hardly reproduce it, but for the production website, we can still see fairly many logging lines showing the intermittent occurrences (and I'm sure that many of them are from using `T(…)` in razor views, not just from the `ISomeService` as when I could easily reproduce the exception the first time).

Please note that the code above is not good, it's not me writing it originally (we have a team of several members). And I know it should be refactored but it's not the right time to do it, even fixing this issue as I've done is just a quick solution).

Comment: It does seem weird and buggy, and yes, there might be an Orchard issue here, but I think your code is buggy as well: since your string manager has a disposable dependency, shouldn't it also be disposable?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I'm not sure that's kind of buggy, actually I added `IDisposable` for the `ITranslator` so that I can add some logging to help debug this issue (printing some message). I assume that the `LocalizedStringManager` does not need to implement `IDisposable` to be disposable, right? Without `ITranslator`  implementing `IDisposable`, the exception is still thrown (the issue is exactly like what I've described).

Comment: Actually my `ITranslator` does use some `IRepository`. I can see that the `DefaultLocalizedStringManager` (provided in `Orchard` source code) does not use any `IRepository` (via its dependencies inside). Currently I'm working around this by avoiding using `IRepository` (such as by moving its related functions to another separate service - keep `ITranslator` service as simple as possible, such as to contain just some preloaded dictionary data).

Comment: I'm confused. How would `LocalizedStringManager` be disposable without implementing `IDisposable`?

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy I think that interface helps other libraries know that the object does have custom disposing logic (that can be run via `Dispose` method), in this case the `Dispose` method is empty so it should be nothing different from explicitly implementing `IDisposable`. All objects will be sooner or later GCed no matter the `IDisposable` is implemented or not. Actually the `LocalizedStringManager` does not implement `IDisposable` but I can see when it's disposed via the referenced `ITranslator`.

Comment: I think there is always a default disposing logic such as in this case when the `LocalizedStringManager` is disposed, all the references (as fields) will be disposed in turn. If you have custom logic for disposing, you can let it implement `IDisposable` and put all logic in `Dispose` method.

Comment: You shouldn't count on the GC: you don't know when that's going to happen. If you don't need the class to be disposable, don't implement the interface. Now I'm confused about something else: how does it matter what dependencies the default implementation does or doesn't use?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I'm not sure how it could matter, I'm also not sure how Orchard checks for disposed object (before continuing, exactly when it checks at `IRepository`), so when I don't use `IRepository`, it does not check that and no exception is thrown, instead all the results are pulled from some static pre-loaded data (at least I looked in the default implementation of `ILocalizedStringManager` and have seen that)

Comment: I don't think it does, it's normal behavior that an object would throw if you try to use it after it's disposed. Since you said it didn't *need* to be disposable, why implement the interface at all? Essentially, you should let Orchard manage the lifetime of your dependencies. Just inject what you need and use it.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I think you did not understand my purpose of implementing `IDisposable` here. My actual code does not have that feature. My actual code does have exception thrown exactly as what I posted in my question. So I was really confused about what's wrong here and wondered which is disposed? why it's disposed? And then I tried debugging it, I did not know any better way to inject my logging line (to know if the `IRepository` is actually disposed and when it's disposed), so I setup all the `IDisposable` to put the logging line in `Dispose` method.

Comment: You said as if the exception would not be thrown, if I did not use `IDisposable`.

Comment: OK, then can you show the actual code that uses `IRepository`?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy please see my update. I've already had a work-around (but may be a better) solution in which `IRepository` is not used at all when `Translate` is called. That shows that really using `IRepository` in this case can cause problem. You can see my update section to imagine better how `IRepository` was used in my case (I personally do not feel/see anything special, it's just special about the `T` and `ILocalizedStringManager`, not sure how yet).

Comment: Thanks for providing that additional code. Unfortunately, I still don't see what exactly is wrong with it. However, the use of `IRepository` always is a bit tricky and is generally considered an [anti-pattern in Orchard](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/just-forget-that-repository-t-exists-please) (and elsewhere). The interface is intended for internal use, as an implementation detail of the higher-level data access layers.What I suspect is happening here (but I can't tell for sure) is that the repository is not appropriately using the ambient transaction/session. You'd avoid those issues by...

Comment: ...querying from the database session instead of the injected repository. Actually, there's [a module on the gallery](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/Orchard.Module.Q42.DbTranslations) that looks pretty close to what you're trying to do, and from what I can see in the code for their localization service, they are querying from the session in SQL directly. I'd have gone for HQL myself, if only to avoid the tenant prefix gymnastics they have to do there, but it's still a good sample to look at for something close to your use case.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy thank you for your feedback. Actually we all moved to using `IRepository` everywhere possible in our project, almost ignore the seemingly convenient `IContentManager` provided by Orchard. The reason for that is we  experienced very slow loading with that (not sure if we setup the models incorrectly ...). At first I thought using `Join` or `As<>` can cause this but actually just using `Query` can cause the slowness although not very clear as using `Join` and `As`. So for a quick solution, we moved all to `IRepository`, we have no time to investigate...

Comment: I asked a question here about that slowness https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507342/accessing-info-from-commonpart-is-extremely-slow . It's interesting that it's you who tried to help me there, but really I'm sorry that I have no time to try anything to confirm anything (and actually your feedback there was still unclear to me for what to try and do).

Comment: Oh. Well. I did give you two possible solutions. Not sure what more I could have done. In this instance, I really advise against using `IRepository`. Even using raw SQL through the `CreateSQLQuery` API of the session is preferable (although there are better ways). You should really take a look at the module I linked above.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy thanks, I'll take a look at it later. Really I'm too busy now with many issues, bugs, ...digging in anything deeply is not an option.